# How can I solve Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript

While trying to push element in array, I receive an error:

> main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'document')
> at main.js:1:50

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button id="input">Click Here</button>

  <script>
    const newItem = document.getElementById('.input').document.addEventListener('click', function(addNewItem) {
      let move = ["L", "L", "R", "F", "N"];
      const newMove = move.push('newItem');
      console.log(newMove);
    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('.input').document.addEventListener`  -> `document.getElementById('.input').addEventListener` and also fix your lookup: `".input"` doesn't seem like an ID. Either you want `"input"` for an element with `id="input"` or maybe you want `querySelector` instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Voiting to Close** - This decision stems from the fact that this was caused by a simple typo, and is not an actual reproducible problem that can be solved logically.

Comment: Please check your code thoroughly before posting it to a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

###### There are two mistakes in your code.

1. You are targeting the `id` by using `document.getElementById(".input")`, however; ***id*** in html is `input` not `.input`. You have to remove `.` before `input`.

- Remove `document` before `document.addEventListener`

  ```
  document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', function (arg) 
  {

  });
  ```

###### I have included a modified example of your code below with the appropriate corrections.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button id="input">Click Here</button>

    <script>
        const newItem = document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('click', function (addNewItem) {
            let move = ["L", "L", "R", "F", "N"];
            const newMove = move.push('newItem');
            console.log(newMove);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused by `document.getElementById('.input')`. which returns null. There is not `.input` element, you need to use the correct spelling, like this: `'input'`